# How to Optimize React Calendar Rendering for Selected Days Without Unnecessary Re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm building a calendar with React, where I can perform horizontal scrolling between different weeks. So, I have a FlatList that renders the weeks, and inside it, for each week, it renders another FlatList with the days of the week. I've set initialNumToRender={4} and maxToRenderPerBatch={8} with these values. Getting to the point, I have state that manages the selected day, but changing the state is slow. I've applied all possible optimization techniques, such as memo, useMemo, and useCallback. However, the issue is specific in the sense that every time the date changes, I compare in the second FlatList of days to see if it's selected (to highlight the day), and this causes a re-render of all the weeks, even those where the day is not present. How can I solve something like this? Has anyone else encountered a similar situation?

I tried implementing various optimization techniques, including using memo, useMemo, and useCallback, to improve the performance of my React calendar when selecting days.

I expected that changing the selected day would only trigger a re-render of the specific day cell, rather than causing all the weeks to re-render.

However, what actually happened was that every time I changed the selected day, it led to a re-render of all the weeks, including those where the selected day was not present. This resulted in a noticeable performance lag when navigating the calendar.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the desired behavior and prevent unnecessary re-renders of unrelated components in my calendar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent re-rendering in react-native-calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76637584/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-in-react-native-calendars)